# How to customize android passwordToggleDrawable

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Android support library added TextInputLayout adding several features like floating label and password toggle visisbilty

My problem is How to customize passwordVisisbilityDrawable so my own icons for visible and hidden state will be displayed.

Also when I enable passwordToggleVisibility, height will increase.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

for change drawable, create a selector like below

password_toggle_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_visible" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_hidden"/>
</selector>
```

then assign to TextInputLayout like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/PasswordLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    **app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle_drawable"**
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.CommonTextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

for height, I used below code after inflating:

```
CheckableImageButton text_input_password_toggle = (CheckableImageButton) PasswordLayout().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.text_input_password_toggle);
text_input_password_toggle.setMinimumHeight(0);
PasswordEditText().setMinHeight(0);
PasswordEditText().setMinimumHeight(0);
```

Comment: Using
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_visible" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_hidden" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>`
made this work for me.

Comment: How would I do findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.text_input_password_toggle); in androidx

Comment: This answer is now deprecated. You can use the same solution, but set `app:endIconDrawable` to your selector xml instead

Comment: It's not 100% working. Icon's colour is different than actual drawable icon colors.

Comment: I had to add app:passwordToggleTint="@null" to the TextInputLayout as well. I guess the tint is overriding the drawables. With no tint the correct selector drawables where showing for the checked true/false states.