# Custom passwordToggleDrawable is too large in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have used android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout to make a password input that allows the user to toggle readability on the password. The xml is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle_selector"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The drawable selector is as described by [How to customize android passwordToggleDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397979/how-to-customize-android-passwordtoggledrawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/password_toggle_show" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/password_toggle_hide"/>
</selector>
```

**The issue** is that the custom drawable becomes really large. Not larger than the edittext, but rather it seems to maximize its size while still fitting inside it (so, it seems to be bounded by the height of the element). However, if I leave the passwordToggleDrawable property unset, the drawable for the toggle is sized as is normal for android (I am sure you have seen the icon in other apps before). After much searching I have found a way to resize the custom one, but I am not happy with how its done (requires 2 *extra* xml files per drawable) and it only works for API 23+.

- *I would like to know if there is a good way to set the size of the drawable, or better yet, make it target the size of the default drawable?*

**I have tried** setting the padding of the EditText as the source of TextInputLayout says that it gets the four paddings from it and apply to the mPasswordToggleView (line 1143), but it made no change on the icon and (as expected) also affected the padding of the EditText. I have tried setting minheight to 0. I have also tried changing between EditText and TextInputEditText (using the latter now as it seems to be recommended). I have tried switching the layout_height properties to wrap_content. I have tried scaling the drawable using xml's `<scale>` tag with the scale properties set. I have tried similarly with the `<inset>` tag. *But none of those methods works.*

The way I found (and am currently using) to resize the drawable **that actually works** is by using the xml tag `<layer-list>`, while setting the width and height properties. Then the `<selector>` xml file references those resized drawables instead of the png ones. But I don't like this solution because as I mentioned it requires API 23 and because of that results in a total of 4 extra xml files. It also sets the width and height by themselves, instead of keeping the ratio locked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/password_toggle_hide"
        android:width="22dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

**TL;DR**
How do I set the size of a custom passwordToggleDrawable in TextInputLayout? Preferably to same size as the default drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I were unable to find any solution to the question I actually asked, but I decided to instead solve the issue by disregarding the *"in InputTextLayout"* part of the question and implemented my own version of the class.

Mostly it is just a copy of InputTextLayout (sadly that class doesnt translate well for subclassing as everything is private) but with most of the stuff I dont need removed, and more importantly, with the `CheckableImageButton mPasswordToggleView` changed to a `ViewGroup` containing a `View`.

The `ViewGroup` is the clickable button, and handles setMinimumDimensions to keep the clickable area at min 48 dp, like the original did through `design_text_input_password_icon.xml`. This also makes small drawables not hug the right side of the screen as they are centered in the clickable area, giving the margin that the default drawable appears to have.

The `View` (or more precisely, a new subclass of it I called `CheckableView`) is the actual drawable (`setBackground()`), replacing the `CheckableImageButton` as the container of the drawable that lets it switch based on `state_checked` selector.

The xml-property `passwordToggleSize` allows a dimension to be set, which is used to scale the drawable. I opted to only have one value instead of width&height, and the drawable scales with its ratio locked such that its greatest dimension matches the dimension specified. I made the default size 24dp, as is specified for the default-drawable in `design_ic_visibility.xml`.

PasswordToggleLayout.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.AbsSavedState;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.mylifediary.android.client.R;

public class PasswordToggleLayout extends LinearLayout {

    // Default values from InputTextLayout's drawable and inflated layout
    final int BUTTON_MIN_SIZE = 48; // The button is 48 dp at minimum.
    final int DEFAULT_DRAWABLE_SIZE = 24; // The default drawable is 24 dp.

    int mButtonMinSize;

    final FrameLayout mInputFrame;
    EditText mEditText;

    private boolean mPasswordToggleEnabled;
    private Drawable mPasswordToggleDrawable;
    private CharSequence mPasswordToggleContentDesc;
    ViewGroup mPasswordToggleViewGroup;
    CheckableView mPasswordToggleView;
    private boolean mPasswordToggledVisible;
    private int mPasswordToggleSize;
    private Drawable mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable;
    private Drawable mOriginalEditTextEndDrawable;

    private ColorStateList mPasswordToggleTintList;
    private boolean mHasPasswordToggleTintList;

    public PasswordToggleLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PasswordToggleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PasswordToggleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setAddStatesFromChildren(true);

        mButtonMinSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, BUTTON_MIN_SIZE,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        mInputFrame = new FrameLayout(context);
        mInputFrame.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
        addView(mInputFrame);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout, defStyleAttr,
                R.style.Widget_Design_TextInputLayout);

        mPasswordToggleEnabled = a.getBoolean(
                R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout_passwordToggleEnabled, false);
        mPasswordToggleDrawable = a.getDrawable(
                R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout_passwordToggleDrawable);
        mPasswordToggleContentDesc = a.getText(
                R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout_passwordToggleContentDescription);
        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout_passwordToggleTint)) {
            mHasPasswordToggleTintList = true;
            mPasswordToggleTintList = a.getColorStateList(
                    R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout_passwordToggleTint);
        }
        mPasswordToggleSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.PasswordToggleLayout_passwordToggleSize,
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                        DEFAULT_DRAWABLE_SIZE, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

        a.recycle();

        applyPasswordToggleTint();
    }


    private void setEditText(EditText editText) {
        // If we already have an EditText, throw an exception
        if (mEditText != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "We already have an EditText, can only have one");
        }

        mEditText = editText;

        final boolean hasPasswordTransformation = hasPasswordTransformation();

        updatePasswordToggleView();

    }

    private void updatePasswordToggleView() {
        if (mEditText == null) {
            // If there is no EditText, there is nothing to update
            return;
        }

        if (shouldShowPasswordIcon()) {
            if (mPasswordToggleView == null) {
                // Keep ratio
                double w = mPasswordToggleDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                double h = mPasswordToggleDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                double scale = mPasswordToggleSize / Math.max(w,h);
                int scaled_width = (int) (w * scale);
                int scaled_height = (int) (h * scale);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.END | Gravity.RIGHT);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        scaled_width, scaled_height, Gravity.CENTER);

                mPasswordToggleViewGroup = new FrameLayout(this.getContext());
                mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setMinimumWidth(mButtonMinSize);
                mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setMinimumHeight(mButtonMinSize);
                mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mInputFrame.addView(mPasswordToggleViewGroup);

                mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        passwordVisibilityToggleRequested(false);
                    }
                });

                mPasswordToggleView = new CheckableView(this.getContext());
                mPasswordToggleView.setBackground(mPasswordToggleDrawable);
                mPasswordToggleView.setContentDescription(mPasswordToggleContentDesc);
                mPasswordToggleView.setLayoutParams(lp2);
                mPasswordToggleViewGroup.addView(mPasswordToggleView);
            }

            if (mEditText != null && ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(mEditText) <= 0) {
                // We should make sure that the EditText has the same min-height
                // as the password toggle view. This ensure focus works properly,
                // and there is no visual jump if the password toggle is enabled/disabled.
                mEditText.setMinimumHeight(
                        ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(mPasswordToggleViewGroup));
            }

            mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

            mPasswordToggleView.setChecked(mPasswordToggledVisible);

            // Need to add a dummy drawable as the end compound drawable so that
            // the text is indented and doesn't display below the toggle view.
            if (mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable == null) {
                mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
            }
            // Important to use mPasswordToggleViewGroup, as mPasswordToggleView
            // wouldn't replicate the margin of the default-drawable.
            mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable.setBounds(
                    0, 0, mPasswordToggleViewGroup.getMeasuredWidth(), 1);

            final Drawable[] compounds = TextViewCompat.getCompoundDrawablesRelative(mEditText);
            // Store the user defined end compound drawable so that we can restore it later
            if (compounds[2] != mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable) {
                mOriginalEditTextEndDrawable = compounds[2];
            }
            TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(mEditText, compounds[0],
                    compounds[1], mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable, compounds[3]);

            // Copy over the EditText's padding so that we match
            mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setPadding(mEditText.getPaddingLeft(),
                    mEditText.getPaddingTop(), mEditText.getPaddingRight(),
                    mEditText.getPaddingBottom());
        } else {
            if (mPasswordToggleViewGroup != null
                    && mPasswordToggleViewGroup.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
                mPasswordToggleViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable != null) {
                // Make sure that we remove the dummy end compound drawable if
                // it exists, and then clear it
                final Drawable[] compounds = TextViewCompat.getCompoundDrawablesRelative(mEditText);
                if (compounds[2] == mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable) {
                    TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(mEditText,
                            compounds[0], compounds[1],
                            mOriginalEditTextEndDrawable, compounds[3]);
                    mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyPasswordToggleTint() {
        if (mPasswordToggleDrawable != null && mHasPasswordToggleTintList) {
            mPasswordToggleDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mPasswordToggleDrawable).mutate();

            DrawableCompat.setTintList(mPasswordToggleDrawable, mPasswordToggleTintList);

            if (mPasswordToggleView != null
                    && mPasswordToggleView.getBackground() != mPasswordToggleDrawable) {
                mPasswordToggleView.setBackground(mPasswordToggleDrawable);
            }
        }
    }

    private void passwordVisibilityToggleRequested(boolean shouldSkipAnimations) {
        if (mPasswordToggleEnabled) {
            // Store the current cursor position
            final int selection = mEditText.getSelectionEnd();

            if (hasPasswordTransformation()) {
                mEditText.setTransformationMethod(null);
                mPasswordToggledVisible = true;
            } else {
                mEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                mPasswordToggledVisible = false;
            }

            mPasswordToggleView.setChecked(mPasswordToggledVisible);
            if (shouldSkipAnimations) {
                mPasswordToggleView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
            }

            // And restore the cursor position
            mEditText.setSelection(selection);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPasswordTransformation() {
        return mEditText != null
                && mEditText.getTransformationMethod() instanceof PasswordTransformationMethod;
    }

    private boolean shouldShowPasswordIcon() {
        return mPasswordToggleEnabled && (hasPasswordTransformation() || mPasswordToggledVisible);
    }


    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            // Make sure that the EditText is vertically at the bottom,
            // so that it sits on the EditText's underline
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams flp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(params);
            flp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                    | (flp.gravity & ~Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK);
            mInputFrame.addView(child, flp);

            // Now use the EditText's LayoutParams as our own and update them
            // to make enough space for the label
            mInputFrame.setLayoutParams(params);

            setEditText((EditText) child);
        } else {
            // Carry on adding the View...
            super.addView(child, index, params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        updatePasswordToggleView();
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.isPasswordToggledVisible = mPasswordToggledVisible;
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        if (ss.isPasswordToggledVisible) {
            passwordVisibilityToggleRequested(true);
        }
        requestLayout();
    }

    static class SavedState extends AbsSavedState {
        boolean isPasswordToggledVisible;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        SavedState(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
            super(source, loader);
            isPasswordToggledVisible = (source.readInt() == 1);

        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeInt(isPasswordToggledVisible ? 1 : 0);
        }

        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader) {
                return new SavedState(in, loader);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in, null);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }


    public static class CheckableView extends View {
        private final int[] DRAWABLE_STATE_CHECKED =
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked};

        private boolean mChecked;

        public CheckableView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CheckableView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CheckableView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            if (mChecked != checked) {
                mChecked = checked;
                refreshDrawableState();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
            if (mChecked) {
                return mergeDrawableStates(
                        super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace
                                + DRAWABLE_STATE_CHECKED.length), DRAWABLE_STATE_CHECKED);
            } else {
                return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in an attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="PasswordToggleLayout">
    <attr name="passwordToggleEnabled" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="passwordToggleDrawable" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="passwordToggleContentDescription" format="string"/>
    <attr name="passwordToggleTint" format="color"/>
    <attr name="passwordToggleSize" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I faced the same problem and I believe I figure out a simple solution for this.

I'm using the TextInputLayout for the newest material library, and the only thing that I did was to find the reference for the endIcon from the TextInputLayout and change it's minimum dimensions.

```
val dimension = //here you get the dimension you want to
val endIconImageView = yourTextInputLayout.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.text_input_end_icon)
endIconImageView.minimumHeight = dimension
endIconImageView.minimumWidth = dimension
yourTextInputLayout.requestLayout()
```

Important things to notice:

I did this on the `OnFinishedInflated` from a custom TextInputLayout, but I believe it will work fine on some activity class.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, that worked wonderfully. I had to convert the `dimension` from `dp` first using `TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30f, resources.displayMetrics)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16456117/1440785

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. To avoid this situation I used png and set them based dpi like drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi etc. Also make those drawable as per radio. Hope that this tricks also work for you.

Comment: I would rather not do it that way, thanks for the suggestion though. I made a class similar to TextInputLayout instead (cant simply extend it to override and mess with dimensions, because everything is private...) that gives me what I need. Will post it once I am satisfied with it and mark it as my own answer in absence of anything better. Although still not happy that it needs to copy so much of the code instead of being able to just reference a superclass, but its better than other options at least.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. The problem comes from the gradle material API implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

downgrade to version 1.0.0 fixes the issue:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```